# Converting Tree Like File Directory to a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, treeview

I'm trying to convert a file directory response into a JSON object. 
Here's a copy of the response from the file directory function.

```
[ 'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/email',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/email/FreddyMcGee@Gmail.com',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/etc',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/etc/etc',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/password',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/password/123123123213',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/username',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/username/Freddy1337' ]
```

And this is the ouput that i'm trying/aiming to achieve:

```
1 : {
    email: "FreddyMcGee@Gmail.com",
    etc: etc,
    password: "12313123",
    username: "Freddy1337"
}
```

Simply the shortest path in the directory is the start of JSON object. All previous 'folder directories' are clipped.

I've attempted myself to write a function that does so, however I had some trouble since the folder 'Users' appears twice. Also the function doesn't traverse the nodes properly, it just cuts it at set sections and glues them together. It's very horrible, i'm a bit ashamed.

```
function TreeToJson(directory, cutAfter){
    for (var i = directory.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        directory[i] = directory[i].substr(directory[i].indexOf(cutAfter) + cutAfter.length, directory[i].length - 1);
        directory[i] = directory[i].split("/");
        directory[i].shift();
    };
    jsonA = {}; jsonB = {}; jsonC = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
        if(directory[i][2] != undefined){
        jsonB[directory[i][2]] = directory[i][3]
        }
    };
    jsonC[Number([directory[0][1]])] = jsonB;
    jsonA[directory[0][0]] = jsonC;
    return jsonA;
}
TreeToJson(files, 'Objects');
```

If someone can show me a better approach into converting a 'Tree View Model' into a 'JSON Object' i'd appreciate it. I'm curious on the approaches other developers would take, and also what the most simplest solution would be.

Comment: Are the "values" (eg `123123123213`) always immediately after the "keys" (eg `password`) in the input?

Comment: Yup, however it'd be cool to see a function without the limitation of those "keys" being the most indepth property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very common operation is extracting the part of the string after the last slash, so I'd make a regular expression function for that. Identify the starting directory name from the first element in the array, and then use a simple `for` loop to iterate through the rest of the array, two-by-two, extracting the keys and values:

```js
const input = [
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/email',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/email/FreddyMcGee@Gmail.com',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/etc',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/etc/etc',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/password',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/password/123123123213',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/username',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/username/Freddy1337'
];
const lastPart = str => str.match(/\/([^\/]+)$/)[1];
const [baseDirectory, ...keysVals] = input;
const dirName = lastPart(baseDirectory);
const dirObj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < keysVals.length; i += 2) {
  const key = lastPart(keysVals[i]);
  const val = lastPart(keysVals[i + 1]);
  dirObj[key] = val;
}
const output = { [dirName]: dirObj };
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Pretty creative approach, a bit curious on this line;
[baseDirectory, ...keysVals] = input; 
Haven't really seen something like that in JS before.
Thanks for the advice/tip buddy.

Comment: It's called spread syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1):

you can split by 'Users' and `.reduce()` the resulting array :

```js
const data = ['C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/email',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/email/FreddyMcGee@Gmail.com',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/etc',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/etc/etc',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/password',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/password/123123123213',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/username',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/username/Freddy1337'
];

const objects = data
  .map(e => {
    return e.split('Users')[2];
  })
  .reduce((all, curr) => {
    let elems = curr.split('/');
    all[elems[1]] = all[elems[1]] || {};

    if ([elems[2]] && elems[3]) {
      Object.assign(all[elems[1]], {
        [elems[2]]: elems[3]
      })
    }
    
    // elems[1] is : 1
    // elems[2] is the key ( username, password .. )
    // elems[3] is the value ( Freddy1337 ... )
    
    return all;
  }, {})

console.log(objects)
```

EDIT : same code above wrapped in a function :

```js
const tree = ['C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/email',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/email/FreddyMcGee@Gmail.com',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/etc',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/etc/etc',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/password',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/password/123123123213',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/username',
  'C:/Users/Freddy/System/storage/Objects/Users/1/username/Freddy1337'
];

function TreeToJson(data, cutAfter){
  const objects = data
    .map(e => {
      return e.split(cutAfter)[1];
    })
    .reduce((all, curr) => {
      let elems = curr.split('/');
      all[elems[2]] = all[elems[2]] || {};

      if([elems[3]] && elems[4]){
        Object.assign(all[elems[2]], {
          [elems[3]] : elems[4]
        })
      }

      return all;
    }, {})
    
 return objects;
}

console.log(TreeToJson(tree, 'Objects'))
```